# Convert String date to UTC format

Tags: java

Looks bit silly. But spend a day to find out the solution.
Currently we save data in the database like: **2022-11-30 21:59:59+00**
I want to convert this to UTC format. i.e **2022-11-30T20:59:59Z**.

I did write method to convert above to UTC

```
private static void dateToUTC(String source) {
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    try {
        System.out.println("Date--------------> : "+ source);
        //Date date = sdf.parse(source);
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .parse(source);
        System.out.println("Date------date--------> : "+ date);
        //System.out.println("Date------date--------> : "+ date.toInstant());
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        String s = zdt.toLocalDateTime().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString();
        System.out.println("Working ---------------> "+zdt.toLocalDateTime().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
        System.out.println("SSSSSSSS--------------> : "+ s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
dateToUTC("2023-03-08 10:20:09.891+00");
dateToUTC("2023-01-12 08:32:10+00");
dateToUTC("2015-06-12 00:10:10");
```

last is working fine. But first 2 are not converting.

```
Date--------------> : 2023-03-08 10:20:09.891+00
Date------date--------> : Wed Mar 08 10:20:09 GMT 2023
Working ---------------> 2023-03-08T10:20:09Z
SSSSSSSS--------------> : 2023-03-08T10:20:09Z
Date--------------> : 2023-01-12 08:32:10+00
Date------date--------> : Thu Jan 12 08:32:10 GMT 2023
Working ---------------> 2023-01-12T08:32:10Z
SSSSSSSS--------------> : 2023-01-12T08:32:10Z
Date--------------> : 2015-06-12 00:10:10
Date------date--------> : Fri Jun 12 00:10:10 BST 2015
Working ---------------> 2015-06-11T23:10:10Z
SSSSSSSS--------------> : 2015-06-11T23:10:10Z
```

Could someone assist me please to convert GMT to UTC.

Comment: Can you explain it, what is not working in first two formats ?

Comment: Note that UTC isn't a format, it's related to time zones. Additionally, I'd expect 2022-11-30 21:59:59+00 to be equivalent to 2022-11-30T**21**:59:59Z as the "+00" normally means "an offset of 0 hours from UTC".

Comment: You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Avoid `SimpelDateFormat` & `Date`.

Comment: What database engine? And *exactly* what data type of your column?

Comment: You should be exchanging date-time objects with your database, not strings.

Comment: You're right. It's datetime in DB but retrieving datetime as String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use differents patterns for the first and second examples:

dateToUTC("2023-03-08 10:20:09.891+00");

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX").parse(source);
```

dateToUTC("2023-01-12 08:32:10+00");

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX").parse(source);
```

Comment: With a switch case based on the length of the date string.

Comment: First parser works if mili seconds exists. Second parser works if no mili seconds. But my case is same database column can contain mili seconds or may not contain mili seconds. However +00 will be exists

Comment: You can use Pattern matching to test and choose what date pattern you will parse. That is for the longest one: `Pattern.compile("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3}[+-]\\d{2}").matcher("2023-03-08 10:20:09.000+00").matches()`

Answer (score 2):

When you are working with database you should use `OffsetDateTime` to store an instant on the universal timeline to nanosecond precision.

> OffsetDateTime adds to the instant the offset from UTC, which allows the local date-time to be obtained. We can use OffsetDateTime when modeling date-time concepts in more detail, or when communicating to a database or in a network protocol.

[Read more](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/parse-string-to-date-time-utc-gmt/)

Try this example code:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXXXXX");

//Date string with offset information
String dateString = "03/08/2019T16:20:17:717+05:30";

//Instance with given offset
OffsetDateTime odtInstanceAtOffset = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

//Instance in UTC
OffsetDateTime odtInstanceAtUTC = odtInstanceAtOffset.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

//Formatting to string
String dateStringInUTC = odtInstanceAtUTC.format(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);

System.out.println(odtInstanceAtOffset);
System.out.println(odtInstanceAtUTC);
System.out.println(dateStringInUTC);

//Convert OffsetDateTime to instant which is in UTC
System.out.println(odtInstanceAtOffset.toInstant());
```

Output:

```
2019-08-03T16:20:17.717+05:30
2019-08-03T10:50:17.717Z
03/08/2019T10:50:17:717Z
2019-08-03T10:50:17.717Z
```